# c++ templated function calling

Tags: c++, function, oop

```
template <class ElementType>

Event<ElementType>::Event(){
    Queue<ElementType> q = *new Queue<ElementType>();

}


int main(){
    Queue<class ElementType> q = *new Queue<ElementType>();

    Event<ElementType> evt = *new Event<ElementType>();



    evt.simulation();

    return 0;
}


template <class ElementType>
void Event<ElementType>::simulation(){
    Queue<ElementType> bankLine = *new Queue<ElementType>();
    PriorityQueue<ElementType> eventpqueue = *new PriorityQueue<ElementType>
();

    bool avalteller = true;
    bankLine.
    while(!(bankLine.template bankline.isEmpty<ElementType>())){
        //file reader
        Queue<ElementType> newEvent = bankLine.peek();
    }





    while(!eventpqueue.template eventpqueue.isEmpty<ElementType>()){
        PriorityQueue<ElementType> newEvent = eventpqueue.peek();

        int cTime = newEvent.getTime();

        if(newEvent.template getType<ElementType>() == "A"){
            processArrival(newEvent, eventpqueue, bankLine);

        }
        else{
            processDeparture(newEvent, eventpqueue, bankLine);
        }
    }

}
```

Can I ask how can i call Queue bankLine and PriorityQueue eventpqueue??

I searched to call those function and I did it this way but I get unqualified-id error with XCODE.

Queue and PriorityQueue are different header files each other and they both have cpp file. and I wish to call `bankLine.isEmpty()` function and `eventpqueue.isEmpty()`.

Comment: You have memory leaks all over the place. Don't use `new`.

Comment: thanks!!! I will try not to use new!

Comment: Do you mean that you have cpp files for template classes?  Template classes and their functions should all be declared in the same `.h` file..The compiler need to have the entire template class, including the function bodies in the `.h` file so it can generate the code on demand.